# Prove that $G \cong \pi_{1} (X/G)$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

This is a question from an exam.

Let $X$ be a topological space which is [simply-connected](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplyConnected.html), and let $G$ be a group of homeomorphisms of $X$ which acts properly discontinuously, meaning

$$\forall \ x\in X,\ \exists\text{ open neighbourhood } U \text{ such that }\  \forall \ g \in G  \setminus {e},\ U \cap g(U) = \emptyset. $$

We need to show that $G \cong \pi_{1} (X/G)$.

I would appreciate any hints or clarification for the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more context and details to your question? As it stands the question body is not very clear, and your question is likely to be closed. Moreover the term "group of isomorphism spaces" is not familiar to me so maybe you should elaborate on what you mean by that. Please see the community post on Asking A Good Question for tips on how to make your question more clear https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: In order for us to answer the question you should in particular tell us what you already know, because depending on your background a solution to this problem could either be straightforward or require some work. Does this problem come from a particular course or book that you're working through?

Comment: sure I try to add more useful detail. @William

Comment: You haven't really addressed the issues I pointed out. It's clear that the goal is to show $G\cong \pi_1(X/G)$, but without telling us where the problem is coming from or about what you already know in relation to the problem we don't know what tools are available to us (or you), and there's not much sense in answering your problem using concepts you haven't learned yet. For example, is this from a chapter about covering spaces? Do you know about covering spaces? Do you know that covering spaces have the homotopy-lifting property? Do you know about universal covering spaces?

Comment: actually any clarification is helpgful, I knew fundamental groups, covering spaces and universal covering spaces and the homotopy lifting property for them. this was my exam question so I don't know which chapter will cover it truly. @William

Comment: I see. Do you mind if I edit your question to clear that up? (If you don't like the edit it can be rolled back)

Comment: sure, my pleasure. @William

Comment: ok I've added that in and cleaned up the presentation of your question a bit. There is one more thing I forgot to mention: math.SE has a semi-formal policy against "No clue" questions, where the asker simply poses the problem without demonstrating that they have tried anything yet. You should include any attempt you've made on the problem or any ideas you have to solve it, and then the question will be more likely to be well-received by the community.

Comment: For details on the "No clue" issue, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Thanks for your edit@William

Comment: Thanks I read it. @LeeMosher

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key to this problem is noticing that the condition on the action of $G$ implies that the quotient map $q\colon X \to X/G$ is a covering space. (**Hint:** for each $x\in X$ we can choose a neighbourhood $U$ satisfying the given condition, and then $q(U)\subset X/G$ will be evenly covered $q^{-1}(q(U)) = \cup_{g\in G}g\cdot U$.)

Then since $X$ is simply connected it is actually the *universal* covering space of $X/G$, and from here you can prove $\pi_1(X/G) \cong G$ in a number of ways. Here are some suggestions:

1. Prove that $G$ is the automorphism group (aka group of Deck transformations) of $q$.
2. For each basepoint $x_0\in X$ the fibre over $q(x_0)$ is the $G$-orbit $\{g\cdot x_0\mid g\in G\}$, which is in bijection with $G$. Use path/homotopy lifting to construct a map $\pi_1(X/G, q(x_0)) \to G$ and show it is a bijective homomorphism.
3. Use the long exact sequence of a fibration (if you know it).

---

Since OP requested it in a comment, I will try to elaborate on the third suggestion.

A covering space $E\to B$ with fibre $F$ satisfies the homotopy lifting property with respect to any space, or in other words it is a fibration (specifically a Hurewicz fibration). In particular a covering spaces satisfies the homotopy-lifting property for CW complexes (aka a Serre fibration) so it's possible to derive a long exact sequence of homotopy groups
$$ \dots  \to \pi_n(F) \to \pi_n(E) \to \pi_n(B) \to \pi_{n-1}(F) \to $$
$$ \dots \to \pi_1(B) \to \pi_0(F) \to \pi_0(E)$$
where for $\pi_0$ "exactness" is in terms of pointed sets.

Since $F$ is discrete $\pi_n(F) = 0$ for all $n>0$ (in particular $\pi_n(E) \cong \pi_n(B)$ for $n \geq 2$) and if $E$ is simply connected we have $\pi_1(B) \cong \pi_0(F) \cong F$, as *pointed sets*.

In our case we actually have $F = G$, a group, and $B = E/G$, but it remains to show that the bijection $\pi_1(B) \to \pi_0(G)\cong G$ is a homomorphism of groups, and I haven't managed to come up with an argument for this yet.

Comment: Thank you, I enjoyed the way you gave us hint, fibration is a continuous mapping $p : E \rightarrow  B$ satisfying the homotopy lifting property with respect to any space.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you explain the third method more.